# count records with x-'WHERE' statement and assigning that to x-number of variables

Tags: mysql

from the table `realestate` I want to get the
number of records where the field `address` is <= 5 and >= 0 and assign that to `counta`
number of records where the field `address` is <= 12 and >= 6 and assign that to `countb`

and so on....

Comment: why 0 to 5; why 6 to 12? provide more info; i dont see a pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `between` would be easier to read:

```
select
    (select count(address) from realestate 
    where address between 0 and 5) as counta,
    (select count(address) from realestate 
    where address between 6 and 12) as countb
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select count(address) 
        from realestate 
        where address <= 5 and address >= 0) as counta,
       (select count(address) 
        from realestate 
        where address <= 12 and adress >= 6) as countb
```